# Using stored procedures in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, stored-procedures

I am using stored procedures in codeigniter like

```
$success = $this->db->query("call my_stored_proc('arg1','arg2');");
```

and inside the procedure i am updating few table rows. Records are getting updated properly. But when i see firebug i always get error like database error until i use like `SELECT arg1 or SELECT arg2` at the end of stored procs. why is this required. Please help em to understand this.

Comment: Posting the stored procedure code would help more to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$success = $this->db->query("call my_stored_proc('arg1','arg2');", FALSE);
```